# Logitech QuickCam Messenger Communicator webcam drivers

Tags: webcam, driver

Im trying to figure out if I can get the logitech messenger communicator webcam working with the Pi. (no, its not on the supported software list)

In searching for drivers, I came across this link where someone went to the trouble of compiling them.
http://home.mag.cx/messenger/source/
Unfortunately I'm still learning linux, so I'm not entirely sure how (if at all possible) to install these with Wheezy. Is this possible?

Background

- logitech cam plugged into a powered hub
- lsusb: Device 006: ID 046d:08f5 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Messenger Communicate
- Using motion, starts, gets a grey screen - 'unable to open video device'
- ls /dev/video0* shows /dev/video0 which matches /etc/motion/motion.conf

--will try any other suggested troubleshooting

Comment: Try `ls /dev/video*` to get all interfaces. 046d:08f5 seems to be supported by the kernel.

Comment: Not sure if I should see more, that just gives me "/dev/video0"

Comment: Just for a test, try running motion as root, it might be a permission problem.

Comment: As root same deal, no go. I borrowed a different cam from work, and it works fine. So yeah...not sure how, if possible to get this one going